# Should [dc-animated-universe] become the primary tag name rather than [dcau]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

DCAU is the abbreviation for the franchise called the [DC animated universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe). On this site the primary tag used for it is [dcau](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dcau), with [dc-animated-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-animated-universe) as a synonym. But there is no length limit issue here, so is it not better to use [dc-animated-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-animated-universe) as the primary tag?

Even for the film universe, the primary tag is [dc-extended-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe) and the synonym is [dceu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dceu). So why not do the same for DCAU? It can be easily done using mod tools without affecting the front page.

Comment: But does anyone _call_ it DC Animated Universe? Most people shorthand it to DCAU in my experience, which makes it a better fit as a primary. Perhaps others have different experience? All in all, I don't have a strong opinion either way, just pointing out that DCAU is extremely common.

Comment: I have heard it called both way equally and even timverse etc.

Comment: Petition to rename it DC-timverse!

Comment: Even if you are really serious Timmverse at beast can be a synonym

Comment: Note that this is already the case with `marvel-cinematic-universe` and `dc-extended-universe`, where the longer tag is the main, and there are shorter tags as synonyms.

Comment: Given the +7/-0 voting on SQB's answer, I've just swapped the synonymisation, so that all the DCAU questions are now showing up tagged with [tag:dc-animated-universe] rather than [tag:dcau]. For some reason the tag page for [tag:dc-animated-universe] still redirects to [tag:dcau], but I'm guessing that's just a caching issue. Ping me in a few days to let me know whether it's working as it should, and I'll either poke around further to fix it or mark this as [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Randal'Thor caching issue always occur while swapping synonyms or creating new but it's working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes

Making [dc-animated-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-animated-universe) the primary tag is clearer for a user unfamiliar with the material and less likely to be confused with [dceu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dceu).

If a user tries to tag with [dcau](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dcau), after typing `dca`, the proper tag name will show up either way.

Comment: Last time it took me days to clean wrongly tagged DCAU questions due to edit limit